# Trying to find string within a string

Tags: regex

Totally new to Regex.
Hope this hasn't been answered previously. Sorry if it has.

My issue is trying to get names from a string from within a string.
not sure if I have my head wrapped around the best options for this.
This is a small extract from the total string block

```
 <div class="txt-block" itemprop="contractors" itemscope
 itemtype="home"> 
                             <h4 class="inline">Employs:</h4> <a href="/.../" itemprop='url'><span class="itemprop"
 itemprop="name">Carp 1</span></a>,  <a href="/.../"
 itemprop='url'><span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Carp
 2</span></a>,  <a href="/.../" itemprop='url'><span class="itemprop"
 itemprop="name">Carp 3</span></a>                          <span
 class="tots">|</span>
                           <span class="see-more inline"> <a href="/.../" itemprop='url'>See full options</a>                      
 </span>
                          </div>
```

I would like to extract "Carp 1", "Carp 2", "Carp 3".
String length varies as does the number of items I would like to extract.

Maybe there is even an easier way to do this.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: will the keyword "Carp" will remain the same?

Comment: Do not use regex with HTML.

Comment: I'd suggest using Javascript to retreive the text inside the `<span></span>` tags.

Comment: It seems like a job for a HTML parser.

Comment: [Here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)'s a nice blog post on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Regex question. You would need html parsing via HTML DOM and XPath.

see these links for ref:

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** this was posted before the question was formatted to show that it is a question about parsing HTML.

This regex assumes you are parsing a plain text string like:

```
Employs: carp1, carp2, carp3 | blah blah...
```

*Generally speaking, you shouldn't use a regex to parse HTML.  However, if you use another method to remove all of the HTML tags first, you could use this approach on the plain text that results.*

Generally, this is best accomplished with a two step process:

First get the portion of the string you want:

```
my $carps;
if ($string =~ /Employs:\s*([^|]+)/)
{
    $carps = $1;
}
```

Then get each item out of the matched portion.  You can use a regex if necessary, but in this case it looks as though a simple split would suffice:

```
my @carps = split /,\s*/, $carps;
```

(Using Perl as an example, but this approach should work in any language).

Answer (score 0):

Since the string you're searching for is enclosed between a span tag with a class and item attribute:
`<span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">STRING</span>`

You may use the following regex:

`<span.*?(?:itemprop\s*=\s*"\s*name\s*"\s*)?class\s*=\s*"\s*itemprop\s*"\s*(?:itemprop\s*=\s*"\s*name\s*"\s*)?>(.*?)<\/span>`

See it in [action](http://regex101.com/r/hT3vJ8) with some explanation, and don't forget the regex modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

use some xml parser. For sample program use following link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4826/XML-File-Parsing-in-VB-NET